# How can I adjust the length of a column field in bash using awk or sed?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I've an input.csv file in which columns 2 and 3 have variable lengtt.

```
100,Short Column, 199
200,Meeedium Column,1254
300,Loooooooooooong Column,35
```

I'm trying to use the following command to achieve a clean tabulation, but I need to fill the 2nd column with a certain number of blank spaces in order to get a fixed lenght column (let's say that a total lenght of 30 is enough).

```
awk -F, '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3;}' input.csv
```

My current output looks like this:

```
100   Short Column   199
200   Meeedium Column   1254
300   Loooooooooooong Column   35
```

And I would like to achieve the following output, by filling 2nd and 3rd column properly:

```
100   Short Column               199
200   Meeedium Column           1254
300   Loooooooooooong Column      35
```

Any good idea out there about awk or sed command should be used?
Thanks everybody.

Comment: `column -t input.csv` or take a look at `printf` or `awk`'s `printf`.

Comment: `column -s, -t file` should do it

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you.

Comment: Using [gawk's `FIELDWIDTHS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html) could also be a solution.

Comment: @fedorqui FIELDWIDTHS is for **reading**, not for writing, it won't help with this.

Comment: @EdMorton good one. Noted, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than picking some arbitrary number as the width of each field, do a 2-pass approach where the first pass calculates the max length of each field and the 2nd prints the fields in a width that size plus a couple of spaces between fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *, *"; OFS="  " }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        w[i] = (length($i) > w[i] ? length($i) : w[i])
        if ($i ~ /[^0-9]/) {
            a[i] = "-"
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "%"a[i]w[i]"s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
100  Short Column             199
200  Meeedium Column         1254
300  Loooooooooooong Column    35
```

The above also uses left-alignment for non-digit fields, right alignment for all-digits fields. It'll work no matter how long the input fields are and no matter how many fields you have:

```
$ cat file1
100000,Short Column, 199,a
100,Now is the Winter of our discontent with fixed width fields,20000,b
100,Short Column, 199,c
200,Meeedium Column,1254,d
300,Loooooooooooong Column,35,e

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file1
100000  Short Column                                                   199  a
   100  Now is the Winter of our discontent with fixed width fields  20000  b
   100  Short Column                                                   199  c
   200  Meeedium Column                                               1254  d
   300  Loooooooooooong Column                                          35  e
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Is there's any way to customize the tst.awk (or the command line in bash) in order to start doing the alignment just for  some specific columns? For example: in a csv with 30 columns, I wish to apply the alignment only to columns 20, 21, 22 (because the columns from 1 to 19 are mere headers that I wish to discard from the print).

Comment: Thanks for your tips, the script works perfectly! I wondered if there's any way to modify the tst.awk script in order to get right alignment for digit fields, also in case of some decimals, Currently, the script alignes the amount 1000 at right, but the amount of 1000.99 at left (actually it was my mistake, I didn't specify in my question that digit fields contain decimals) . Probably I should add some code to your line starting with the following:  if ($i ~ /[^0-9]/). Thank you again, awsome code!

Comment: Of course, just add a dot `[^0-9.]`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) in `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{gsub(/ /, "", $3); printf "%-5s %-25s%5s\n", $1, $2, $3}' file input.csv
100   Short Column               199
200   Meeedium Column           1254
300   Loooooooooooong Column      35
```

What I have done above, is set the `IFS`,field separator to `,`; since the file has some white-spaces in the 3rd column alone, it mangles, how `printf` processes the strings, removing it with `gsub` and formatting in C-style `printf`.

Comment: or with bash's printf: `while IFS=, read -r a b c; do printf "%5s %-25s%5s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"; done < file`

Comment: @Inian Good code! Thank you.  Is there's any way to customize the awk in order to start doing the alignment just for some specific columns? For example: in a csv with 30 columns, I wish to apply the alignment only to columns 20, 21, 22 (because the columns 1 to 19 and 23 to 30 are mere headers / footers that I wish to discard from the print).

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)/sprintf "%-6s%-30s%5s", $1,$2,$3/e' input.csv
100   Short Column                   199
200   Meeedium Column               1254
300   Loooooooooooong Column          35
```