# awk - Printing output in 3 column format

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file of data that appears in the following format.

```
apropos c
awk nc
chsh c
date nc
grep nc
i3 nc
ip6tables nc
```

I am trying to filter this data through awk, to produce a 3 column format, similar to below.

```
apropos          awk          chsh
date             grep         i3
```

I do not need the second column of information on the file, but would like a clean and aligned output of the first column. I found the following code elsewhere, and modified it a bit to only output the first column of data. Problem is that it comes out misaligned due to the usage of tabs.

```
awk '{printf (NR %3 == 0 )? $1 "\n" : $1"\t\t" }'
```

Doing a bit more research I found the usage of width via awk's printf (ie. "%-10s"). Only problem is I am not quite sure how to integrate it into my command to get it to do what I'd like. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want `ip6tables` to not appear in the output because its not part of a multiple of 3?

Comment: I'm looking for all of the first column to be outputted. Regardless of it being a multiple of 3.

Comment: Then [edit] your expected output to show that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be more useful to you than hard-coding some arbitrary field width like `10`:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print $1}' file | column -t
apropos    awk   chsh
date       grep  i3
ip6tables
```

or if you do want to drop `ip6tables` from the output as shown in your sample input/output:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec OFS $1} !(NR%3){print rec; rec=""}' file | column -t
apropos  awk   chsh
date     grep  i3
```

If you don't pipe to `column` and don't want to pick some arbitrary number as the field width then you need awk to make 2 passes of the input file to figure out the max width of each column first before printing (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38791539/1745001).

wrt the first example - running any UNIX tool on input that does not end in a newline is relying on undefined behavior per the POSIX spec so if your `column` gives a warning when there's a missing newline after `ip6tables` then add it:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print $1} END{if (NR%3) printf "%s", RS}' file | column -t
apropos    awk   chsh
date       grep  i3
ip6tables
```

Comment: This worked as intended. Any chance I can get a rundown of how your awk statements work? I'm still learning and always interested in understanding.

Comment: @barefly look up ORS, FS, RS, and NR in the awk man pages then re-read the scripts (add some `print`s if needed to see what the values are being tested/set) and you'll probably understand them right away but if not let me know if you have any specific questions and I'll be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk | column` pipe:

```
awk '{sep=NR%3?OFS:ORS;printf "%s%s", $1, sep}END{if(NR%3)print ""}' a.txt  \
  | column  -t
```

Note: Since (at least) the BSD version of the column command will print a warning:

```
column: line too long
```

and omit the last line in case the number of lines in the list is not a multiple of the column count you need to print a newline after the last element in that case.

Answer (score 1):

a non-awk solution

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 <file | paste - - - | column -t

apropos    awk   chsh
date       grep  i3
ip6tables
```

or with `pr`

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 <file | pr -3at

apropos                 awk                     chsh
date                    grep                    i3
ip6tables
```